# API Returning None In Google Collab

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, save, google-colaboratory

I'm writing a code for a project, and this is my first time delving into machine learning. The issue I'm having however, is just in the data collection to train the model. I'm not huge on Google Collab, but am using it for a few reasons, the main thing being this is what my instructor uses to validate our code, if it doesn't run in it, even if the code is correct, we don't get credit (Learned this the hard way, where exit() doesn't work properly in Collab and you have to use kill). Anyways, I'm having issues collecting data using the OpenSkyAPI. I can't get it to return anything, I don't know if collab has certain restrictions or if it's a problem with the code, or something in between. But any help would be appreciated. The code is attached (most of it is still psuedo code, as I said I'm trying to get the data collector done). I'll attach it in code blocks, with each one being it's own block in collab, in case that makes any difference. Any help or even ideas are appreciated! Drop a comment if more info is needed.

Really all I've changed besides the code listed here is trying to specify exactly where the csv files should be saved. Most of the rest is saved here. Besides not saving any files because the API returns none, the code runs perfectly.

Code to install OpenSkyAPI

```
# Installs the OpenSkyAPI:

!git clone https://github.com/openskynetwork/opensky-api
!pip install -e /content/opensky-api/python
```

Class Definitions etc.:

```
# Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import requests as rq
import time
import os
from opensky_api import OpenSkyApi
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_validate
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression  # Add other ML models as needed
from datetime import datetime

# Global variables for API and data storage
api = OpenSkyApi('username', 'password')


# LiveDataCollector class definition
class LiveDataCollector:
    def __init__(self, bounding_box, airport_icao, collection_interval=60, max_iterations=5):  # Reduced for quicker testing
        self.api = OpenSkyApi('username', 'password')  # Replace with actual credentials
        self.bounding_box = bounding_box
        self.airport_icao = airport_icao
        self.collection_interval = collection_interval
        self.max_iterations = max_iterations

    def collect_live_data(self):
        for iteration in range(self.max_iterations):
            print(f"Iteration {iteration + 1} of {self.max_iterations}")
            current_time = int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
            states = self.api.get_states(bbox=self.bounding_box)
            print(states)
            arrivals = self.api.get_arrivals_by_airport(self.airport_icao, current_time - 3600, current_time)
            departures = self.api.get_departures_by_airport(self.airport_icao, current_time - 3600, current_time)

            if states:
                self.save_to_csv([self.state_to_dict(state) for state in states.states], 'state_vectors.csv')
                print(f"Saved state vectors data.")
            if arrivals:
                self.save_to_csv([self.flight_to_dict(flight) for flight in arrivals], 'arrivals.csv')
                print(f"Saved arrivals data.")
            if departures:
                self.save_to_csv([self.flight_to_dict(flight) for flight in departures], 'departures.csv')
                print(f"Saved departures data.")

            time.sleep(self.collection_interval)

    def state_to_dict(self, state):
        return {
            'icao24': state.icao24,
            'callsign': state.callsign,
            'country': state.origin_country,
            'time_position': state.time_position,
            'last_contact': state.last_contact,
            'longitude': state.longitude,
            'latitude': state.latitude,
            'altitude': state.baro_altitude,
            'velocity': state.velocity,
            'heading': state.heading
        }

    def flight_to_dict(self, flight):
        return {field: getattr(flight, field, None) for field in flight._fields}

    def save_to_csv(self, data, filename):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_csv(filename, index=False, mode='a')  # Append mode to continuously add data

# Data Preprocessing Class
class DataPreprocessor:
    def __init__(self, data):
        """
        Initializes the DataPreprocessor with the provided data.

        Inputs:
        - data: DataFrame containing the data to be processed.

        Outputs:
        - None
        """
        self.data = data

    def preprocess_data(self):
        """
        Preprocesses data and performs feature engineering.

        Inputs:
        - None

        Outputs:
        - preprocessed_data: DataFrame containing preprocessed data.
        """
        # Implement data preprocessing steps
        pass

# Machine Learning Model Class
class TrafficModel:
    def __init__(self, preprocessed_data):
        """
        Initializes the TrafficModel with preprocessed data.

        Inputs:
        - preprocessed_data: DataFrame containing preprocessed data.

        Outputs:
        - None
        """
        self.data = preprocessed_data
        self.model = None  # Placeholder for the ML model

    def train_model(self):
        """
        Trains the machine learning model on the preprocessed data.

        Inputs:
        - None

        Outputs:
        - model: Trained machine learning model.
        """
        # Implement model training logic
        pass

# Data Visualization Class
class DataVisualizer:
    def __init__(self, data):
        """
        Initializes the DataVisualizer with the provided data.

        Inputs:
        - data: DataFrame containing the data to be visualized.

        Outputs:
        - None
        """
        self.data = data

    def plot_time_series(self):
        """
        Generates a time series graph.

        Inputs:
        - None

        Outputs:
        - Time Series Graph
        """
        plt.plot(self.data['time'], self.data['metric'])  # Replace 'time' and 'metric' with actual column names
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Metric')
        plt.title('Time Series Graph')
        plt.show()

    # Additional visualization methods (heat maps, histograms, etc.)

# Main Execution Class
class AirTrafficOptimizer:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes the AirTrafficOptimizer.

        Inputs:
        - None

        Outputs:
        - None
        """
        self.data_collector = LiveDataCollector()
        self.data_preprocessor = None
        self.traffic_model = None
        self.data_visualizer = None

    def execute(self):
        """
        Implements the overall process flow of the project.

        Inputs:
        - None

        Outputs:
        - None
        """
        # Implement the overall process flow here
        pass
```

Drives the LiveDataCollector for testing:

```
bounding_box = (39.5283, 39.6117,-104.8870, -104.8114)
airport_icao = 'KAPA'  # ICAO code for Centennial Airport
collector = LiveDataCollector(bounding_box, airport_icao)
collector.collect_live_data()
```